# Django search in a TextField

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-queryset

I'm trying to do a search for a query in Django, the `icontains` lookup works for the `title`(CharField) but not for the `content`(TextField). I want to search if the query exists in the title or content of a post.

Model that I'm using to test queries: (models.py)

```
class BlogPost(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=120, blank=True)
    content = models.TextField(blank=True)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return '{} - {}'.format(self.title, self.user.username)
```

This is the code: (views.py)

```
from django.db.models import Q

...

class BlogPostAPIView(mixins.CreateModelMixin, generics.ListAPIView):

    ...

    def get_queryset(self):
        qs = BlogPost.objects.all()
        query = self.request.GET.get('q')
        if query is not None:
            qs = qs.filter(Q(title__icontains=query) | Q(content__icontains=query)).distinct()
        return qs
```

This is the error I get when making a query:

> Exception Type:   FieldError
>
> Exception Value:  Unsupported lookup 'icontains' for TextField or join on the field not permitted.

Comment: can we see your full `BlogPost` model and all the methods inside as well?

Comment: Question updated with the model that I'm using to test this query.

Comment: are you sure `content` has content? and on the top of that, it's not recommended to set `null=True` to TextField since `None` value may be considered as string `"None"` in field which is not null

Comment: Why don't you change the field in the model to CharField? It really doesn't make much difference.

Comment: Also, which database are you using?

Comment: @Lemayzeur Yes, It's a ListAPIView with some posts and then I search like this: url/api/blogposts/?q='myquery'

Comment: @zmbq There is no size limit? Or any downside in using CharField for long texts? I'm using sqlite3 as default and testing purposes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use

> results = Cancer.objects.filter(abstract__contains='cancer').values_list('title', 'document_id')
>    str(results.query)
>
> 'SELECT "patents_cancer"."title", "patents_cancer"."document_id" FROM "patents_cancer" WHERE "patents_cancer"."abstract"::text LIKE %cancer%'

or 
you can use `Search` for `TextField`
like Entry.objects.filter(body_text__search='Cheese')

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/contrib/postgres/search/

Answer (score 0):

Change your field to a `CharField`. As explained in a comment, you're using SQLite. SQLite [doesn't pose any length restrictions](https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html) on character fields.

Answer (score 0):

You have two choices to solve this
1. Change `TextField` to `CharField`. This will compromise your text storage
2. Use DB such as `MYSQL` , `PostgreSQL` etc

Comment: I'm working with MySQL now, but Django still forces me to use the `max_length` parameter since its a CharField (If I change back to TextField it results in the same error), so what is the difference in using MySQL or SQLite3 on this point?